# sed replace the last characters of the last line on AIX?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, aix

I've this type of .txt file :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
```

I would like to delete `, \` if the last line :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, \
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

On AIX I try :

```
sed "s/\//" test.txt
```

But it doesn't works...

Could you help me ?

Comment: Use `sed '$ s|, \\||' test.txt > output.txt`, see [demo](https://rextester.com/CWUP55785)

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
sed '$ s|, \\||' test.txt > output.txt
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://rextester.com/CWUP55785).

The `$` means only run `sed` on the last line, and `s|, \\||` replaces one occurrence of `, \` with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the file directly, use `ed` instead of `sed` (Especially on AIX, since I'm pretty sure its `sed` doesn't implement the non-standard `-i` option for inplace editing, meaning you have to save its output to a temporary file and then `mv` it to the original name):

```
printf '%s\n' '$s/, \\$//' w | ed -s test.txt
```